# C# - Matrix Printing Incorrectly on a Separate Thread

Tags: multithreading

I'm currently making a Console Application game, and am working on the multiplayer version.

When I am receiving packets, I create a new thread to handle the packets, in order to return to the ReceiveFrom command as soon as possible.

The newly created thread should reprint the whole Matrix, using the new information it got regarding the changes in the matrix (it should print the Matrix with updated player positions).

The problem is, when the Print method is called on the new thread, it is badly performed. It prints the matrix very inaccurately, and many characters of the matrix are just in a mess on the Console Screen.

Here are the methods:

```
    void Receive()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] msg = new byte[1024];
            client.Receive(msg);
            Thread handle = new Thread(() => HandleInput(msg));
            handle.Start();
        }
    }
    void HandleInput(byte[] msgX)
    {
        string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msgX);
        data = data.Replace("\0", "");
        if (data.Contains('*') || data.Contains('\0') || data.Contains(' ')) // Move Packet (moving objects in a matrice)
        {
            // for example, a move packet can be: '*'!12!10
            char ToMove = char.Parse(data.Split('!')[0]);
            int X = int.Parse(data.Split('!')[1]);
            int Y = int.Parse(data.Split('!')[2]);
            grid[X, Y] = ToMove;
            Print();
        }
    }
    void Print() // print a 20x50 matrix
    {
        Console.Clear();
        for (int y = 0; y < 52; y++)
        {
            Console.Write('-');
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Console.Write('|');
            for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(grid[i,j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine('|');
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < 52; x++)
        {
            Console.Write('-');
        }
    }
```

But, when I tried to treat the input and print the matrix on the same thread of the Receive method, it worked fine. The problem printing it only came when I printed the matrix on a separate thread.

So why does this happen? Why can't a separate thread just print the matrix correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You create a new thread for every received kilobyte, but those threads are not guaranteed to start running in sequence, to wait one another, nor to finish running in sequence.

There is also no guarantee that network client will receive all needed bytes in one call of `Receive` method. It may happen in one, but it may happen in several calls. It may also happen that two `Send` methods from the other side of the connection are merged into one message. All that is guaranteed in network communication is the ordering of the bytes in the stream, and nothing else.

Your next question will probably be "so how do I make it work"? I can't do the job for you, but this is in general how I would do it:

1. Read chunk of bytes from the stream and store it in some buffer.
2. Check in the loop for existence of a complete message in the buffer. If there is such a message remove that message from the buffer, and process the message. I would process it in the same thread, and only if there are problems with that approach I would consider additional threads (or rather just one additional thread to whom I would be sending all the messages).
3. Repeat the loop until all complete messages are removed from the buffer, and continue reading the stream.

Comment: OK, Thank you. It does sound like a good idea, but is it just impossible to make the threads run in sequence and not clash with each other?

Comment: It can be done with some guard code but it defeats the purpose having many threads. If you force them to run sequentially then why bother having them so many, and not just one? They take up memory and processor power.

Comment: The reason I want to use multi-threading here, is because using the IF statements in the Receive method itself, will delay the program from receiving again until the IF statements are done (this is very critical when there are hundreds of requests per second). So multi-threading will only make it slower, you say?

Comment: @BlueRay010 multithreading makes things faster only if they use all processor resources. There is some critical number after which more threads do not add more computing power, because processors are already at maximum. After that point more threads start to get in the way of one another. In your case it's even worse because you fire huge number of short lived threads. Thread creation is expensive, and should be reduced to minimum. That's why thread pools are invented.

Comment: @BlueRay010 also, I don't understand your system, but is the same entity (server maybe) going to handle all the clients' communication, AND draw something in the console? What kind of a server is that?

Comment: This is simple, actually - the server receives a packet containing a movement of one of the players, and it sends that packet to all connected clients, without changing it. Once the clients receive that packet, they update the matrix on their own, and then print it in the console. The server doesn't have the matrix. The only thing the server does is to receive packets from clients and then broadcast them to all client, in order that the clients will update their matrix.

Comment: @BlueRay010 so "hundreds of requests per second" are on the client side? You should optimize communication so that clients receive only data that they need. Speed gained in communication is the sweetest gain. In offtopic I think console is a bad way of doing graphics. It was not meant for that purpose, and it could be the bottleneck of the whole process. Go for something else, I don't know, like WPF, anything but console.

Comment: Yeah I know, but currently I'm just practising communication for a 2D game I'll start in a few days. Also, hundreds of packets per second is totally true. Think about a game like Battlefield 4, for example - every bullet shot results in sending of 20-30 packets (every little update in the ball's location requires a packet sending). So let's say in a server, 50 bullets are shot each second? That means 1000-1500 packets per second. All clients should receive it and process it. There's also all other player movement and things like that.

Comment: And also, firing a thread for each request might be expensive, but what would you really do when you have to treat hundreds-thousands of requests per second? Your Receive method has got to be extremely fast, and if you treat the requests on the same thread, the IF statements that check the requests will delay the Receive method from being executed again, thus bringing to a possible packet loss. This is why you have to make your Receive method very fast, and right now, Multi-threading seems the best way to do it. I really can't think of any other efficient way to do this.

Comment: @BlueRay010 in my step two I mentioned that you can have one additional thread instead of unknown big number of them. This one thread could process all the messages that come from receiving thread, and live for the entire game time. This one thread should be enough, and if it's not enough then you have to optimize communication so that less bytes are used to convey more information.

Comment: @BlueRay010 also consider what happens if someone hacks your client or messes with the packets. That person could make his side unbeatable. The server cannot be just a dummy conveyor of bytes. It must control the game itself. The message that server sends to a client is then shorter, "bam! you're dead!" instead of "50 bullets are coming your way, and you figure out if you die".

Comment: One thread does sound like a good idea, but there a few problems associated with it. I can just make one thread, and start it right after receiving a packet, right? But what if the thread takes 2 seconds to die, and the server receives a packet each 1.5 seconds? A exception will be thrown that'll say that I can't start a thread which is already alive (because it is still procession the previous input).

Comment: Also, I've tried benchmarking the server to see which way is less CPU & Memory consuming. When the server didn't use new threads for each packet, it consumed at average 13.6% of my CPU, and 7.9% of my Memory. When it DID use a new thread for each packet, it used at average 14.2% of my CPU and 7.7% of my Memory. The test was done by flooding the server at about 100,000 packets per second for a few minutes. Is a difference of 0.6% CPU usage really significant? My processor is I7 Sandy Bridge 2011, by the way.

Comment: @BlueRay010 one thread for the whole life of the game, not "one thread at a time but huge number of threads for the whole life of the game". Don't create threads, and rather send messages to the one and only already existing thread. The code is more complicated, but more efficient. And as I already said I would avoid even that one thread if it is not in fact needed.